# ¿Se puede crear una tabla que tenga relación consigo misma?

Tags: sql, sql-server, modelorelacional, ssms

Vi algunas preguntas similares, pero no veo que se apliquen a las necesidades que tengo.
Entonces lo planteo.
Estoy creando un programa, que es para llevar las cuentas personales.
En la BDD, tengo la tabla movimientos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y para agendar ese movimiento para que sea repetido las veces que se diga, como por ejemplo compras en 3 cuotas, hice otra tabla para agendarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He aquí el problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo hago para no perder la relación de los pagos futuros con el primer pago?
Se pude agregar un campo que sea tipo IdMovimientoAgendado y que contenga el ID de un mismo campo de la tabla? Es decir que el movimiento 3, o cuota 3 tenga otro campo que lo relacione directamente con el ID del primer movimiento? O simplemente puedo hacer que el ID que se registre como pago 1, se repita hasta que termine de completarse la cantidad de cuotas?

Estaría mal agregar un campo que se relacione con la misma tabla? Algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas un campo principal digamos ClienteId, o ProductoId o TickedId dependiendo conque este relacionado el pago.

Comment: En ese caso, tendría que hacer un campo más llamado (por ejemplo, como decís) TicketID, y lo hago clave primaria compuesta en conjunto con el IdMovimiento de la tabla movimiento? Para luego utilizarlo como foránea de la tabla Agenda. Es así?

Comment: asi es y puedes tener en movimientos o pagos, fecha pago y fecha proximo pago para tu siguiente moviento, sin necesidad de otro registro, asi solo iras contando los pagos hasta el momento,

Comment: Genial. Muchisimas gracias!!! Me simplificaste todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se puede crear una tabla que tenga relación consigo misma como ejemplo te pongo un tabla llamada persona

Una persona por ejemplo tiene su nombre y tiene una madre y un padre que también son personas

Otro ejemplo sería la Tabla trabajador que tiene un salario y un jefe que también es un trabajador

Estas son relaciones recursivas o jerárquicas y se definen creando un campo como llave foránea que apunte a la llave primaria de la propia tabla, ej en la tabla persona habría un campo idMadre que su valor sería el campo llave primaria de otra persona la cual sería la madre del individuo. Parece un trabalenguas pero no lo es, espero hayas entendido en realidad no es tan difícil

Comment: Creeme que lo entendí perfectamente. Muchas gracias por sus respuestas!! <3